# How to validate row numbers on webtable using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Row starts with *0* and ends with *9*.

I tried like this:

```
int counter = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='hour ng-star']//span[text()='"+i+"']");
    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(element.getText());
        if (value == counter) {
            counter++; 
        } else {
            System.out.println("The row does not contain the expected values");
            break;
        }
    }
```

I need to add `else` part for `if (element.isDisplayed()) {` block, where should I include `else` part of first `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the `else` part of the `if` goes right after the closing `}` of the `if` statement, just as you did with the inner `if`, e.g.

```
int counter = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='hour ng-star']//span[text()='"+i+"']"));
    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(element.getText());
        if (value == counter) {
            counter++; 
        } else {
            System.out.println("The row does not contain the expected values");
            break;
        }
    } else {
       // else of if (element.isDisplayed()) 
    }
}
```

Having said that, I noticed a bug and wanted to give other feedback to simplify your code.

1. In your question you indicated that the columns are numbered 0-9 but your `if` only goes from 0-8,

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   ```

   but it should be

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
                      ^ note the added equals sign
   ```
2. By putting the `i` value in the XPath, `...//span[text()='"+i+"']`, you've already verified the text contained in the element so there's no need to `parseInt` and compare the values. Your entire code snippet can be reduced to

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
       WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='hour ng-star']//span[text()='" + i + "']"));
   }
   ```

   This code will throw an `NoSuchElementException` if one of the elements is not present, i.e. the text is not there or in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *`else`* block for `if (element.isDisplayed())` after the *`if()`* completes, i.e.

```
int counter = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='hour ng-star']//span[text()='"+i+"']");
    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(element.getText());
        if (value == counter) {
            counter++; 
        } else {
            System.out.println("The row does not contain the expected values");
            break;
        }
    } else {
    
        // else part of element.isDisplayed()
    }
```